# Computation of different ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am studying Serre's Local fields and I am trying to understand the different/ discriminant definitions. So as an example, I am trying to compute the different of the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]/\mathbb{Q}$.

The inverse of the different is the fractional ideal generated by elements $x\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ such that $Tr(xy)\in \mathbb{Z}$. That would be $<1/2, \sqrt{3}/3>$ I think.

Now I need to compute the inverse ideal of this and I am stuck. Is there an algorithm for these computations?

Comment: Well, I think a quick and dirty method, independent of Serre, is to take your $\theta$ such that the ring of integers is $\Bbb Z[\theta]$ and its minimal $\Bbb Q$-polynomial $f(X)$, and just look at the ideal generated by $f\,'(\theta)$. Sure enough, you get what you want, namely $(2\sqrt3\,)$

Comment: Oh that's a nice trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confess that I’ve always been as uncomfortable with this definition as you seem to be. Let’s look for the minimal (and, I guess, only) integral ideal $I$ such that, calling your ideal $J$, we have $IJ=(1)$. We’re lucky here that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3\,]$ is a principal ideal domain, so we can just multiply by constants. If we multiply only by $2$, we get the basis $\langle1,2/\sqrt3\rangle$, still not integral. Multiply then by $\sqrt3$ and get the basis $\langle\sqrt3,2\rangle$. But the integers $\sqrt3$ and $2$ are relatively prime in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3\,]$. (There are lots of different proofs for this, you supply your favorite one.) That is, $\langle\sqrt3,2\rangle=(1)=\Bbb Z[\sqrt3\,]$.

But the upshot is that we can take $I=\langle2\sqrt3\rangle$, and that’s your different.

Comment: This answer is great not only because of its fine mathematical content, but also for the empathy expressed in the first sentence. (I will second anyone who finds this definition of the different as mysterious as it is elegant!)